# Dataset for computer related jobs

Tags: csv, dataset, data-science

I'm looking for a dataset that contains all the job titles that are related to computer for example:
Data Scientist,
Machine Learning Developer,
Software Developer,
Web Developer,
Python Developer,
etc.

Does anyone know if there is any dataset available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the Adzuna API, they have job listings for all sorts of programming related titles that you can access through their API. You just need to register (for free) and get an API key.

https://developer.adzuna.com/overview